# C# program that ouputs lmstat on remote license server

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

I'm working on my first C# program. I've created a GUI where you select the network-licensed software package in a combobox, and it displays the license usage and statistics in a textbox (lmutil.exe).

Here's the problem: upon first selecting from the combobox, nothing happens, but when you select another software from the combobox list, it outputs the license stats from the previously selected software. Below is the code I have:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ComboBoxItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ComboBox1.Text == "ComboItem1")
        {

            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lmutil.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "lmstat -a -c port@host";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // start the process
            proc.Start();

            string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            TextBox1.Text = s;


        }
        else
        {
            if (ComboBox1.Text == "ComboItem2")
            {

                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lmutil.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "lmstat -a -c port@host";
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                // start the process
                proc.Start();

                string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                TextBox1.Text = s;


            }

            else
            {

                if (ComboBox1.Text == "ComboItem3")
                {

                    Process proc = new Process();
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lmutil.exe";
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "lmstat -a -c port@host";
                    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                    // start the process
                    proc.Start();

                    string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                    TextBox1.Text = s;

                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what GUI library you are using (Window is not a class I recognise, (I use WinForms)) but the following seems to work for me (with a real port and host name substituted for one of the three items (I only have one license server to test with)).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e){
        switch (this.comboBox1.Text){
            case "item1":
                this.textBox1.Text = this.getLMStat(158, "ONE");
                MessageBox.Show("DONE");
                break;
            case "item2":
                this.textBox1.Text = this.getLMStat(158, "TWO");
                MessageBox.Show("DONE");
                break;
            case "item3":
                this.textBox1.Text = this.getLMStat(158, "THREE");
                MessageBox.Show("DONE");
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Unsupported Value");
                break;
        }
    }

    private String getLMStat(int port, String server){
        try {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lmutil.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "lmstat -a -c " + port + "@" + server;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // start the process
            proc.Start();

            return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception){return "Do something with Exception";}
    }
}
```

The message boxes are there so that you know when lmstat has returned, since it hangs for a little while (especially when the port and/or host is invalid).

Are you handling the correct event for the combo box selection changing?

Answer (score 0):

`Process.Start()` starts the process but does not wait for it to finish.  You can call `proc.WaitForExit()` immediately after `string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: Actually that is no problem here because `ReadToEnd` will (as the name suggests) read until the end of the stream is reached - which is, whenever the stream is closed and/or the process is terminated.

Comment: This is still not working for me. Anybody have any ideas?